# Magnetometer sensor error in MPU9150

Tags: c, wiringpi

I coded the following program to get the acc, gyro, magnetic sensor value by using MPU9150 that is connected Raspberrypi 2 via I2c;
I can get the proper acc and gyro value, but the magnetic sensor value is not proper.

I displayed the register value of magnetic X axis (16bit). The High byte is 0x00 or 0xff, and the low byte is consequence value [0x00,0xff] . So, I think that the High byte of magnetic has problem . Please let me know how to resolve it.

> [output ]ex.1 lsb=0e,msb=00,ex.2 lsb=12,msb=00,ex.3 lsb=1d,msb=ff

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>

#define MPU9150_ADDRESS (0x68)     
#define MPU9150_REG_PWR_MGMT_1 (0x6b) 
#define MPU9150_INT_PIN_CFG (0x37)   
#define MPU9150_GYRO_CFG (0x1b)
#define MPU9150_REG_DATA_START (0x3b) 
#define M_I2C_ADDRESS (0x0c)         
#define M_CNTL (0x0A)
#define M_REG_DATA_START (0x03)     

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("MPU9150 starting\n");
    // Setup Wiring Pi
    wiringPiSetup();
    // Open an I2C connection
    int fd = wiringPiI2CSetup(MPU9150_ADDRESS); 

    // MPU6050_REG_PWR_MGMT_1
    wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_PWR_MGMT_1, 0x00);

    wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd,MPU9150_INT_PIN_CFG, 0x02);

    wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd,MPU9150_GYRO_CFG, 0x10);

    int fd2 = wiringPiI2CSetup(M_I2C_ADDRESS);
    wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd2,M_CNTL, 0x01);

    while(1) {
        uint8_t msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START);
        uint8_t lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+1);
        float accelX = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+2);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+3);
        float  accelY = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+4);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+5)
        float  accelZ = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+6);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+7);
        float  temp = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+8);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+9);
        float  gyroX = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+10);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+11);
        float  gyroY = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+12);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, MPU9150_REG_DATA_START+13);
        float  gyroZ = ( msb << 24 | lsb << 16 ) >> 16;

        wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd2,M_CNTL, 0x01);
        delay(10);
        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd2, M_REG_DATA_START);
        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd2, M_REG_DATA_START+1);
        float  magX =  ((int16_t msb << 8 )| lsb ;

        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd2, M_REG_DATA_START+2);
        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd2, M_REG_DATA_START+3);
        float  magY = ((int16_t msb << 8 )| lsb ;

        lsb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd2, M_REG_DATA_START+4);
        msb = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd2, M_REG_DATA_START+5);
        float  magZ = ((int16_t msb << 8 )| lsb ;

        printf("lsb=%x,msb=%x\n",lsb,msb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with the output that you posted.

I'm assuming that the output you posted:

> ex.1 lsb=0e,msb=00,ex.2 lsb=12,msb=00,ex.3 lsb=1d,msb=ff

is 3 separate readings from the magnetometer:

```
lsb=0e,msb=00
lsb=12,msb=00
lsb=1d,msb=ff
```

According to [section 6.4 of the MPU-9150 register map](https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-9150-Register-Map.pdf), those readings are stored as a 16-bit 2's complement number, and are converted to magnetic flux density as:

```
lsb=0e,msb=00 = 0x000e = 14 decimal   =  4.2 uT
lsb=12,msb=00 = 0x0012 = 18 decimal   =  5.4 uT
lsb=1d,msb=ff = 0xff1d = -227 decimal = -68.1 uT
```

Those readings are in the right order of magnitude for the magnetic flux density of the earth's magnetic field, which is about 35 - 60 uT.

If you still think you are getting incorrect data, make sure that you are waiting for the `DRDY` bit in the magnetometer's `ST1` register to be set before reading the magnetometer data.

Comment: Thank you for your replying.

Comment: I misunderstood the right order of magnitude for the magnetic flux density of the earth's magnetic field. The msb is alway  only 2 type of value (0xff or 0x00) , So I misunderstood that this reading value is not corect. But the msb should not change the value  in the earth's magnetic field because iIt is very little value.

Comment: @kkj Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes,Thank you so much.

Comment: @kkj Please accept the answer! See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)